# Почему отменяется hover после изменения цвета background?

Tags: html, css, css3

Друзья, ситуация такая. Есть:

```
<div class="test" onclick="check()">foo</div>
<div class="test" onclick="check()">foo</div>
<div class="test" onclick="check()">foo</div>
```

в CSS:

```
.test{
background:#fff;
}

.test:hover{
background:#f5f5f5;
}
```

в JS

```
function check()
{
  $(".test").css({"background":"fff"});
}
```

ПОЛНЫЙ JS

```
<script>
  function ChooseLine(el)
  {
    if(hexc($("#line"+el).css("background-color"))=="f5f5f5")
    {
      alert(hexc($("#line"+el).css("background-color")));
      $("#line"+el).css({"background-color" : "#ffffff"});
    }
    else
    {
      $(".linetable").css({"background-color" : "#ffffff"});

      $("#line"+el).css({"background-color" : "#f5f5f5"});
    }

    $("#closebutton").css({"display" : "block"});
    $("#editbutton").css({"display" : "block"});
  }

  function hexc(colorval) {
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    delete(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = "0" + parts[i];
    }
    return color = parts.join("");
  }
  </script>
```

после того как нажали на любой из test пропал hover по всем элементам. Может кто то обьяснить почему, и как его вернуть?

Comment: Вставьте код так, чтобы его можно было выполнить здесь. Я скопировал его в jsfiddle.net - там никаких проблем нет, hover никуда не пропадает

Comment: Хорошо, вот полный js который у меня есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас есть ошибка в функции check — надо поставить знак решетки перед FFF, чтобы было:

```
$(".test").css({"background":"#fff"});
```

Во-вторых, стиль при наведении исчезает потому, что `background: #FFF` прописывается в атрибут style, а инлайновые стили имеют наивысший приоритет, потому из CSS цвет не применяется.

---

Если вам надо менять цвет при клике на элемент, то я рекомендую вам добавлять класс, у которого есть соответствующие стили. Также, если я правильно понял логику, вы хотите, чтобы при клике на элемент менялся цвет только у него, а не у всех элементов с классом `test`, следовательно, весь код будет выглядеть вот так:

```js
function check(el) {
  $(el).addClass('selected');
}
```

```css
.test {
  background: #fff;
}

.test:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.selected {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" onclick="check(this)">foo</div>
<div class="test" onclick="check(this)">foo</div>
<div class="test" onclick="check(this)">foo</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло! Логика примерно такая как вы сказали, но еще нужно сбросить цвет если цвет уже применен к конкретному элементу. но это я уже сам. спасибо!)